# Problem with Livestreamer after updating Python to 3.4

Tags: macos, terminal, python

After upgrading to Python 3.4 i get this message when trying to use livestreamer:

```
/usr/local/bin/livestreamer: line 3: __requires__: command not found
/usr/local/bin/livestreamer: line 4: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/pkg_resources
/usr/local/bin/livestreamer: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/usr/local/bin/livestreamer: line 7: `sys.exit('
```

/usr/bin/livstreamer starts

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT:    'livestreamer==1.12.2','console_scripts','livestreamer' 
requires = 'livestreamer==1.12.2' 
import sys
```

Usually I would type "livestreamer [twitch.tv link] best" to run it

I can't figure out what I should do. I have googled for quite a while. I used [this guide](https://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/) to update

Comment: How are you running live streamer? and what are the first 4 lines of /usr/local/bin/livestreamer

Comment: @Mark When i open livestreamer:

#!/usr/bin/python  
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT:   'livestreamer==1.12.2','console_scripts','livestreamer'  
__requires__ = 'livestreamer==1.12.2'  
import sys  

Not sure how i am "running" livestreamer. Usually I would type "livestreamer [twitch.tv link] best" in Terminal
I'm sorry if I am not clear

Comment: I have some problems formatting here with linebreaks. So line 1 is #!usr/bin etc, 2 is # EASY-INSTALL, 3 is requires = (requires has two underscores before and after), 4 is import sys.

Comment: From the code you have not changed python to 3.4 - /usr/bin/python will be Apples system python 2.7 (can you check this and show what running  /usr/bin/python shows) Ah I looked at the guide. Oh well you have corrupted Apple's system I would reinstall OS and ask why you want python 3.4?

Comment: @Mark Oh no. I thought I might have to reinstall :/. I updated because I got an error message about SSL Connections whenever I ran Livestreamer. In the error msg it said that newer versions of Python would correct this. Thank you very much for your help, I am grateful.

Comment: I think you did something wrong in the steps from the guide (e.g.  /usr/bin/python has gone wrong) + also python code is either for version 2 or 3 not both so you would need another livestreamer